# Faster way to populate a table in Django

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I use for loop in Django to populate a table, like this.

```
{% block table_1 %}
    {% for label in results %}
        <tr>
            <td class="col_1">{{ label.0 }}</td>
            <td class="col_2"">{{ label.1 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here "results" is a list, it works just fine if the list is small (len(list) <= 150).

However, most of the time I have large lists, usually contain ten to a hundred thousand items. It significantly slowing down the response. For a list with 200,000 items, it took about two minutes to open the web page.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Paginating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/) your results page will speed it up greatly.
Nobody wants a table with 200k rows anyway

Comment: What if I limit the list's length to say a thousand, for loop tag in Django is still too slow...

Comment: That might help. Paginating works well. But to get to the bottom of the problem, you'll need more info. How many queries are being run to generate the page?